# При сборке контейнера docker игнорируется команда setfacl

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, acl

Подскажите, пожалуйста, вопрос по ACL в docker/
При сборке контейнера docker игнорируется команда в dockerfile

```
RUN setfacl -m u:data:rw /etc/msmtprc
```

При входе в уже запущенный контейнер команда работает успешно
Получается проблема на этапе сборке, но нужно что бы было именно автоматизировано задание прав

Docker version 19.03.13-beta2, build ff3fbc9d55

Answer (score 1):

Специфика сборки образа такова что слои наслаиваются друг на друга при каждом из выполнении различных команд при сборке. Можно предположить что setfacl не сохраняет состояние между слоями либо при построении слоев файловая система не умеет в setfacl... в общем сложно сказать.

Однако же если вы говорите что в контейнере acl работает, то есть смысл тогда комбинировать entrypoint и cmd где в entrypoint явно указываете нужные вам правила acl тогда при каждом запуске контейнера у вас будут выставлен корректные права.

p.s. я тут бегло загуглил, вот еще что обнаружил https://stackoverflow.com/a/22715283/3725361